# How to generate targets in a Makefile by iterating over a list?

Tags: shell, makefile

CODE:

```
LIST=0 1 2 3 4 5
PREFIX=rambo

# some looping logic to interate over LIST
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
rambo0:
    sh rambo_script0.sh

rambo1:
    sh rambo_script1.sh
```

Since my LIST has 6 elements, 6 targets should be generated. In future, if I want to add more targets, I want to be able to just modify my LIST and not touch any other part of the code.

How should the looping logic be written?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [text-transforming functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Functions.html#Functions). With `patsubst` you can make quite general transformations. For constructing filenames, `addsuffix` and `addprefix` are both convenient.

For the rules, use [pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage).

The overall result might look something like this:

```
LIST = 0 1 3 4 5
targets = $(addprefix rambo, $(LIST))

all: $(targets)

$(targets): rambo%: rambo%.sh
    sh $<
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to see the targets in their final generated form?

Comment: @Lazer Not that I know of, but I'm far from an expert with make. The `-n` (dry run) option might tell you what you want.

Comment: @Lazer, `$(info the targets are $(targets))`

Answer (score 32):

If you're using GNU make, you can generate arbitrary targets at run-time:

```
LIST = 0 1 2 3 4 5
define make-rambo-target
  rambo$1:
         sh rambo_script$1.sh
  all:: rambo$1
endef

$(foreach element,$(LIST),$(eval $(call make-rambo-target,$(element))))
```

Comment: Not the most elegant solution for the question that was asked, but this *is* the answer I was looking for: a way to generate targets at run-time.

Comment: This is terribly inefficient for the question asked, but a very good example if this is what you actually want to do.

Comment: @BUFU what's the terrible inefficiency?

Comment: @'idelic' Defining a macro which defines multiple specific targets instead of a pattern rule for all those (systematically named) targets.

Comment: How is that inefficient? Besides, the question is not how to use pattern rules with systematically named targets, but how to generate those targets programatically.

Comment: @Idelic It is inefficient by typing 7 lines instead of 4 and by eval'ing and calling a macro however many times  instead of letting make decide which rules are actually needed. If you use this construct for a million rules, it will take forever for make to actually start doing anything, because it will spend quite some time just constructing rules that are never called. With a simple pattern rule this is no issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents to @Idelic answer, if you need to use some Make `$cmd` you must escape them using `$$`
e.g.

```
LIST = 0 1 2 3 4 5
define make-rambo-target
$(info create target: $(addprefix rambo_script, $(addsuffix .sh, $1)).)
rambo$1: $$(addprefix rambo_script, $$(addsuffix .sh, $1))
    sh $$<
endef

all: $(addprefix rambo, $(LIST))

$(foreach element, $(LIST), $(eval $(call make-rambo-target,$(element))))
```

output:

```sh
$ make
create target: rambo_script0.sh.
create target: rambo_script1.sh.
create target: rambo_script2.sh.
create target: rambo_script3.sh.
create target: rambo_script4.sh.
create target: rambo_script5.sh.
sh rambo_script0.sh
sh rambo_script1.sh
sh rambo_script2.sh
sh rambo_script3.sh
sh rambo_script4.sh
sh rambo_script5.sh
```

note: here rules "are seen" by Make as

```
rambo0: $(addprefix rambo_script, $(addsuffix .sh, 0))
    sh $<
```

But here we could have written without escaping i.e.

```
rambo$1: $(addprefix rambo_script, $(addsuffix .sh, $1))
    sh $$<
```

So rule "are seen" as:

```
rambo0 : rambo_script0.sh
    sh $<
```

when Make parse it.